# I am trying to make a GUI in Java and when I make a JButton with an actionPerformed method, I get a ton of errors that output to the console

Tags: java

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type new ActionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type new ActionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type new ActionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Login extends JFrame {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 350);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Username");
    label.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
    panel.add(label);

    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
    panel.add(userText);

    JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    passLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
    panel.add(passLabel);

    JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField();
    passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
    panel.add(passwordText);

    JButton button = new JButton("Login");
    button.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            count++;
            label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
        }
    });
    panel.add(button);

    JLabel success = new JLabel("");
    success.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
    panel.add(success);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type new ActionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

    at Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:36)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Change this `public class Login implements ActionListener {` to this `public class Login implements {`

Comment: The compiler is expecting the main Login class to have a `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method, and you don't give it one (you *do* give this to the anonymous inner ActionListener class, but that doesn't count for the main class), but if you're not using the class as an ActionListener, better to not even declare it as implementing the interface.

Comment: I put the actionPerformed method outside of the inner ActionListener class but I still get the same errors.

Comment: No, don't do that. Again, remove the `implements ActionListener` from the main class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *remove the implements ActionListener from the main class.* - exactly. Why would this be closed as a duplication of some question that has a typo?  Even the first comment here has a typo because "implements" is still left in the suggestion. No wonder the OP is confused.

Comment: Hey guys, that still doesn't work and I get the same errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: @camickr Right. In the linked duplicate the OP had failed to properly implement `ActionListener`, but here the error is that `ActionListener` was needlessly being implemented. Those are qualitatively different errors, so voting to reopen.

Comment: @JaredBuehner Regarding _"I get the same errors"_, please update your question to show your current source code and your current errors.

Comment: @skomisa I changed it. Not sure if you get notifications for me editing.

Comment: @JaredBuehner, Go back to your very original code that you posted with the question. The only change you need is to remove the "implements ActionListenerr" from the class. You use an anonymous inner class for tor the ActionListener of the button, so there is no need for the class to implement the ActionListener. There is no need to create the "LoginSuccessful" class. Also, you will need to make sure you have the proper imports for the "ActionEvent".

Comment: @skomisa here is the original code.

Comment: Post the code properly. There should 4 spaces before each line so it is displayed as code (ie with the shaded background). I have fixed your code twice. And fix the compile errors. I don't even know how you can execute the code if it doesn't compile. Delete any old class files you have.

Comment: Got it. I posted it properly, but stack overflow wanted me to add more of a description. Where can I find old class files and how do I know what to delete?

Comment: The class files will be of the form "Login*.class". I don't know how you are compiling. If you use the command line they will be in the same directory as your source code. If you use an IDE then they might be in a different directory, I'm not sure since I don' t use an IDE. 1) You still don't have the proper import for the `ActionEvent`! I already mentioned this was a problem. 2) the "count" variable is not defined. Why are you posting code without fixing your errors?

Comment: @camickr I use an IDE. Thank you so much for the help. After adding the ActionEvent import it is working!